# Default activity not found, even though it is declared in Manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have not found the solution to this online. All of my activities are declared, however often Android Studio will tell me it does not find them. It doesn't always occur, and it seems to happen quite randomly. I've cleaned, invalidated and restarted, rebuild, sometimes this will get fixed then start happening again after some time. I'm working in a team on the project, and I seem to be the only one with the bug:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="fall2018.csc2017.GameCentre"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SlidingTiles.SlidingGameActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Score.MenuScoreboardsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Score.UserScoreboardActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Score.ScoreScreenActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Score.GameScoreboardActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".GameLauncherActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SlidingTiles.SlidingTilesStartingActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Simon.SimonGameActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Simon.SimonStartingActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ChooseDimensionActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fall2018.csc2017.GameCentre"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Select run configuration as `app` from the drop-down list left to the run button in Android Studio

Comment: Installation Options: Deploy is "Default APK", Launch options has Launch: "Default Activity"

Comment: if possible in your free time try re-installing android studio

Comment: Do not edit configurations let it as is. Check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzAqQ.png)

Comment: The configurations were left by default

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is the exact issue based on the only information you provided. But, few things you can try to find the issue:

- Try running your app on a different physical device or emulator. If
  it fixes it, that means that was a device issue.
- Set breakpoints on all of your onCreate methods activities, as well as the previous code snippet where the activity will be launching the following activity, for example:

  > Intent intent = new Intent(context, className);
  >               intent.setFlags(intFlag);
  >               context.startActivity(intent);

And try to debug to see if the activity is being created or being launched. This could be a good start to narrow down the problem. *Good luck!*

FYI, switch this line :
`<activity android:name=".ChooseDimensionActivity"></activity>`
to this:

```
<activity android:name=".ChooseDimensionActivity"/>
```